# How to Send mail from visual basic 2010 professional

Tags: email, smtp, system.net.mail, system.net

I want to send a mail using gmail id, my code is as here under, but an error occurred. How can I solve this?

```vb
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MsgBox("This will send a mail...")
        Try

            Dim smtpserver As New SmtpClient()
            Dim mail As New MailMessage()
            smtpserver.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("myname@gmail.com", "password")
            smtpserver.Port = 465
            smtpserver.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
            mail = New MailMessage()
            mail.From = New MailAddress("myname@gmail.com")
            mail.To.Add("to mail id")
            mail.Subject = "Test by bharat"
            mail.Body = "hello ooooooooooooooooooooooo"
            smtpserver.Send(mail)
            MsgBox("Mail Sent")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            Close()
        End Try


    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: whats the error u have got???

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of sending an email with visual basic 10, First you need to build a form with fields to,from,text,and email_send button now the below code

```
Private Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient()

Private Sub email_send_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles email_send.Click
Try

Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("yener.turkeli@v-basic.net", "password")
Smtp_Server.Port = 25
Smtp_Server.Host = "mail.v-basic.net"
e_mail = New MailMessage()
e_mail.From = New MailAddress(from_txt.Text)
e_mail.To.Add(to_txt.Text)
e_mail.Subject = "VB.NET Email Sending"
e_mail.Body = text_txt.Text
Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)

Catch error_t As Exception
MsgBox(error_t.ToString)
End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new class called 'Mail'. 
If you make a class, you don't have to type all of the code again if you want to send more than 1 email.

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public NotInheritable Class Mail
    Public Property subject As String
    Public Property body As String
    Public Property receiver As String

    Public Sub send()
        Try
            Dim smtpServer As New SmtpClient()
            Dim mail As New MailMessage()
            smtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = False
            smtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("yener.turkeli@v-basic.net", "password"))
            smtpServer.Port = 587
            smtpServer.EnableSsl = True
            smtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"

            mail = New MailMessage()
            mail.From = New MailAddress("yener.turkeli@v-basic.net")
            mail.To.Add(receiver)
            mail.Subject = subject
            mail.Body = body
            smtpServer.Send(mail)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message & vbNewLine & ex.StackTrace)
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

And then you can make a new object in your code where and when you want to send the email:

```
Dim email as new Mail
email.receiver = "receiver@example.com"
email.subject = "Subject"
email.body = "Message"
email.send()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        Try
            Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
            Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
            Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
            Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "Password")
            Smtp_Server.Port = 587
            Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
            Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"

            e_mail = New MailMessage()
            e_mail.From = New MailAddress(TextBox1.Text)
            e_mail.To.Add(TextBox2.Text)
            e_mail.Subject = "Email Sending"
            e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
            e_mail.Body = txtmsg.Text
            Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
            MsgBox("Mail Sent")

        Catch error_t As Exception
            MsgBox(error_t.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```